# Should static data be stored in a database or in the application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database-design

I'm working on some software at them moment and I'm not sure which route to take with this.  I have data that will never change, and has a hierarchical relationship, and will be used to populate the display. There is a reasonably amount of this data.

I have the following options:

1.A set of enums/objects
2.An XML file
3.The embedded SQLite database

In this particular case I think that the enums is the most correct way, but I get a smell from the data being embedded in the code like that.  Also i need the data for hierarchy purpose , and using enums look like a bit trouble.

The database should provide less of a performance hit and easy to use, but seems like overkill for static data.

Which is the correct design path here?

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet of what your data looks like?

Comment: Quiz type  which never change, i have 4 type of quiz. Question types, which also rarely change, some question has text answer, some has more than one answer and so on.

Comment: Can you provide an estimate of how much data there is?

Comment: I think the easiest way to lock primary keys and then query accordingly the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the format here, this isn't an "answer"; it's more a series of questions that you will need to answer for yourself, in choosing how to represent this data.

In my (way too many years of) experience, "Static Data which will never change" almost never is truly static.  That would argue for storing the data in a form that does not require source code changes, which would rule out enums.

Example:

> I developed a system for determining the best way to cut up animal
>   carcasses, based on the weight and breed of the available carcasses,
>   and the incoming order stream.  One of the key inputs to this decision
>   process is a description of the anatomy of the animals, identifying
>   which cuts of meat are derived from which muscle groups, and
>   therefore what parts are left once you take out a particular cut. 
>   This information is hierarchical in nature.
>
> You would think that this information would be quite static; after
>   all, the anatomy of the animals does not change.  But in fact, we
>   found that we needed to enhance the data about once every 6 months,
>   adding descriptions of new ways to cut.
>
> Because I thought of the data as static, I described it in an XML file
>   and read it in at the start of the program.  But editing the data in
>   this form was cumbersome and error-prone.  If I had it to do over, I
>   would definitely have chosen a different storage form.

Consider what you would need to do to your program if this static data were to change.  Would you need to add new decision logic and new types, or would it strictly be a matter of changes in relationships among existing objects?  How will you debug the data?  Will you maintain the data in source control?

I would also give consideration to the way(s) in which you want to access this data.  The more flexibility you need in searching it, the better the argument for a database of some kind.  @rbaghbanli's point is also well-taken; your decision might be based on the platform where your code will run.

Comment: I've made a desicion. When application starts, i will store the default data into the database and lock their primary keys.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the type of application you are building. If it is enterprise system or application you better store it in your enterprise database. If it is lightweight user app or mobile app, you better store it as embedded JSON string. XML is a bit too verbose.

Comment: I have to respectfully down-vote this because in my opinion, I think it's more important to consider how the data is being used and less important what the type of the application is when determining the proper storage for your data. The logic of "it's an enterprise system so you should use an enterprise database" doesn't hold for me. I will grant you, however, that platform-dependent considerations, like mobile, are important as they have strict limitations on available memory.

Comment: There are other considerations, though, in an enterprise system.  What are the enterprise policies regarding backup, security, retention, disclosure, etc?  None of these are strictly technical, but they all might play into this decision.